# Is it correct to say "You're sitting sideways in the stroller. Please turn to face forwards / Please turn to face straight ahead"?

Tags: word-usage, word-request, phrase-usage, phrase-request

[image]

Look at the picture.

Is it correct to say:

- **You're sitting sideways in the stroller. Please turn to face forwards / Please turn to face straight ahead!**

Comment: I don't know exactly why you keep getting down votes on these kinds of questions, but if you could specify a problem and explain your confusion, that might help prevent close/down votes. That's my best guess, but maybe someone else could give other suggestions.

Comment: It has occurred to me that maybe people vote them down because they are telling a depressing story of a strict regime of control over a little child?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You're sitting sideways in the stroller.

This is fine.

2. Please turn to face forward*!
3. Please turn to face straight ahead!

These are fine. However, "turn to" is somewhat redundant. There's nothing wrong with that, but *face forward/straight ahead* is sufficient:

4. Please face forward!
5. Please face straight ahead!

It looks like you want the child to sit properly in the seat. That way, the child's back is straight and against the seat, and the child will also be facing you. Then you can simply say

> 6. Please sit up straight.

Arguably, either *up* or *straight* is sufficient, but 6. sounds natural to me.

> [up](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/up) adverb
> (5) : in or into an upright position
> //sit up
> *especially* : out of bed
>
> (M-W)

---

<sub>* A user suggested *face forward* as opposed to *face forward**s***. I did not initially balk at *face forwards*, but upon consideration, *face forward* (no *s*) is preferable to me. A couple of sources make the distinction that *forward* is used as an adjective and *forward**s*** is used as an adverb in BrE, and that *forward* (no *s*) is preferred in either case in AmE ([Macmillan: foward (usage note)](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/forward_1); [Forward vs Forwards (ELU)](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/3885/149070)).</sub>

Comment: I'd think "Please face forward!" not "Please face forwards!" Typo maybe?

Comment: Thanks. I didn't initially think _forwards_ was wrong per se, but I do like _forward_ better. I did a little research that suggests a possible distinction and tried to make a note of it.

Comment: Why can't the poor little bugger sit how he wants? No wonder he "cries for his mom".